# Can't separate color and linetype legends for combined geom_point and _line plot with ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of data frames, sample dataframe is provided:

```
> head(Moment.girder$`UG-84`)
   Int_Multi Spacing    UG    Names N_b
5  0.3350849      12 UG-84 Proposed   5
11 0.3478547       9 UG-84 Proposed   6
17 0.3490468      12 UG-84 Proposed   6
23 0.4013708       9 UG-84 Proposed   4
29 0.4093982       9 UG-84 Proposed   5
35 0.4108012      12 UG-84 Proposed   4
```

I am trying to plot the data such that the color shows girder spacing and the line type shows the types of equations. I use the following code:

```
for (i in 1:length(Moment.girder)) {
Plot.girder <- ggplot(Moment.girder[[i]], aes(x = as.factor(N_b), y = Int_Multi)) +
 geom_point(data = subset(Moment.girder[[i]], Names == "Analytical"),
            aes(colour = factor(Spacing,levels = c("9","12","15")))) +
 geom_line(data = subset(Moment.girder[[i]], Names == "Proposed"),
            aes(colour = factor(Spacing,levels = c("9","12","15")), 
                group = factor(Spacing,levels = c("9","12","15"))), linetype = "dotted") +
 geom_line(data = subset(Moment.girder[[i]], Names == "Henry's Method"),
            aes(colour = factor(Spacing,levels = c("9","12","15")),
                group = factor(Spacing,levels = c("9","12","15"))), linetype = "solid") +
 labs(x = element_blank(), y = element_blank(), 
         title = paste0("Moment Live Load Distribution Factors \n Ultra-Girder Section: UG-"
                       ,str_extract(names(Moment.Plot)[i],"\\d+")),
  colour = "Girder Spacing (ft):") + theme_classic() +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(45,0,20,0), 
                                face = "bold", size = 18), 
         legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "bottom", 
         legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
         legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,0))
print(Plot.girder)
}
```

But my legend is combined for the lines and the colors. I am not sure how I can separate these two into two sperate legends

[image]

Comment: This looks as if the data might be better structured into "longer" format. However, without sight of a minimal set of your data this is speculative. The question would also benefit from being stripped down into a minimal example. Have a look at [mre] and [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Besides the minimal reproducible example mentioned by @Peter, what type of elements do you want to appear in the legend?  Based on your code above, I am assuming that you want one for color (to show girder spacing) and one for method for the values of "Analytical", "Proposed", and "Henry's Method" (which would be a combination of points and line).

Removing the lines from color is easy by providing the `show.legend=FALSE` within each of your `geom_line` pieces.

Comment: Just to add to @statstew's comment it is helpful to be absolutely explicit about the construction of multiple legends, i.e. your desired output: for each legend state 1) the legend title, 2) the legend text and 3) how you want each legend element to be distinguished. Hope these helps in your endeavours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your answer to @Peter's second comment above, here is a stab at what you might want using some data generated at random.

```
library( tidyverse ) # Unsure if you were already using this package

girders.dat <- data.frame( N_b=rep(4:6,each=3), Spacing=rep(c(9,12,15),3) )
plot.dat <- vector( "list", 3 )
plot.dat[[1]] <- data.frame( Int_Multi=runif(9,0.7,1.1) ) %>%
  cbind( ., girders.dat ) %>%
  mutate( Names="Henry's Method", shape_line="H" )
plot.dat[[2]] <- data.frame( Int_Multi=runif(9,0.5,0.8) ) %>%
  cbind( ., girders.dat ) %>%
  mutate( Names="Analytical", shape_line="A" )
plot.dat[[3]] <- data.frame( Int_Multi=runif(9,0.3,0.5) ) %>%
  cbind( ., girders.dat ) %>%
  mutate( Names="Proposed", shape_line="P" )
plot.dat <- plot.dat %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate( pgrp=paste0(Spacing,Names) ) %>%
  mutate( Spacing=factor(Spacing,levels=c("9","12","15")) )

plot.dat %>%
  ggplot( aes( x=as.factor(N_b), y=Int_Multi ) ) +
  geom_line( aes( linetype=shape_line,group=pgrp ), color="black" ) +
  geom_point( aes( shape=shape_line) ) +
  geom_point( data=subset(plot.dat,Names=="Analytical"),
              aes( shape=shape_line, colour=Spacing ) ) +
  geom_line( data=subset(plot.dat,Names=="Proposed"),
             aes( colour=Spacing, linetype=shape_line, group=pgrp ),
             show.legend=FALSE ) +
  geom_line( data=subset(plot.dat,Names=="Henry's Method"),
             aes( colour=Spacing, linetype=shape_line, group=pgrp ),
             show.legend=FALSE ) +
  scale_shape_manual( values=c("A"=19L,"H"=NA,"P"=NA),
                      labels=c("Analytical","Henry's Method","Proposed") ) +
  scale_linetype_manual( values=c("A"="blank", "H"="solid", "P"="dotted"),
                         labels=c("Analytical","Henry's Method","Proposed") ) +
  labs(x = element_blank(), y = element_blank(),
       title = paste0("Moment Live Load Distribution Factors \n Ultra-Girder Section: UG-"
                      ,"DUMMY NAME"),
       colour = "Girder Spacing (ft):", shape="Method", linetype="Method" ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(45,0,20,0), 
                                  face = "bold", size = 18), 
        legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
        legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,0))
```

which produces the following plot

[image]